# Collection View changes the selected cell on scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to select a cell in `UICollectionView`, it gets selected but on scroll down it selects the some other cell on the bottom and scroll up it shows some other to be selected.

Below is the code which I am using `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    NSIndexPath *newIndex = indexPath;

    cell = (CustomCollectionCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:newIndex];

    NSString *strId = [[masterArray valueForKey:@"id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    NSString *tempIndexRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@, %@,%d ,%@, %d", strId,tempIndexRow,cell.imageView.tag,[boolArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],indexPath.row);

    if (strId && [[boolArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"False"] && cell.imageView.tag == indexPath.row) {

        cell.selectedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"];

        [boolArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"True"];
    }
    else{
        cell.selectedImage.image = Nil;

        [boolArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"False"];
    }
}
```

This is what I select for the first time

[image]

This is what I get when I scroll down

[image]

Thanks

Comment: same as like tableview you need to save somewhere which cell was selected and in this method "- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath" manage you image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set selected item index store in to one array and at  `cellForRowIndex` time check this array index with **indexPath.row** like bellow:-

`selectedCellsArray`  alloc this array at `ViewDIdLoad` method

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     cell = (CustomCollectionCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:newIndex];
     if ( [selectedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]]  )
            {
                [selectedCellsArray removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
                cell.selectedImage.image = Nil;


            }
            else
            {
                [selectedCellsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
                cell.selectedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"];
            }
}
```

and

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSNumber *rowNsNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:indexPath.row];
        if ( [selectedCellsArray containsObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",rowNsNum]]  )
        {
           cell.selectedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"];


        }
        else
        {
            cell.selectedImage.image = Nil;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not selecting another cell. Problem is mostlikely due to you reusing cells and not reintializing them correctly when they come back on the screen. When Cells not visible, it unloaded to save memory.

So better check this condtion as well in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` datasource

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

     {

      //You cell initialization code. 

      if ([[boolArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"True"] ) {

            cell.selectedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"select.png"];
        }
        else{
            cell.selectedImage.image = Nil;
        }
    }
```